# How to open a form and then close it after X amount of seconds on c#?

Tags: c#, forms, time, timer

I need to open a form on C# and then have it close automatically after, say, 5 seconds.. The thing is, I need the form to be closed from the form it was opened from because the form I am opening is sometimes opened from another form without being automatically closed.

I've tried this:

```
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetNumber gtn = new GetNumber();
        gtn.Show();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
        gtn.Hide();
        gtn = null;
    }
```

But the form was messed up when it started, same happened when I tried with a timer. 
Anybody know how to solve my problem?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using and what does it mean for "the form to be messed up"?

Answer (score 2):

As itsme86 said, timers would work for what you are trying to do. If you are in .Net 4.5 or greater you can use the async/await features.

At its core, you need to free up the UI thread to continue on its way. Your Thread.Sleep is putting the UI thread out of commission. Using a timer or the async/await allows the UI thread to launch your dialog and process any user actions.

```
private async void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetNumber gtn = new GetNumber();
    gtn.Show();
    await Task.Delay(6000);
    gtn.Hide();
    gtn = null;
}
```

Comment: Can't do, I'm on VS 2008

Comment: Then I would go with itsme86's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A timer would be the correct approach:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetNumber gtn = new GetNumber();
    gtn.Show();

    System.Timers.Timer timer = new Timer(6000);
    timer.Elapsed += (_, _2) => { Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { gtn.Close(); }); };
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the call to Invoke be redundant? Timer calls should be synchronized with the main app thread, if my memory serves me.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Only if you use a System.Forms.Timer, which I didn't. But the OP could go that route if they wanted.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice that. It should be `new System.Timers.Timer` then. ☺ Also it looks `System.Timers.Timer` accepts a SynchronizingObject, which can be set to the current form, so the Invoke can be omitted.